# Operations on multiple selected more than one records of listbox in ASp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send SMS to the all records(numbers) selected from the listbox, so how can i check the slelected numbers from listbox ?

i have tried with following code:

```
foreach(ListItem li in ListBox2 .Items )   
{   
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(EM_MobileNo) FROM ps.employee_master ";
sSQL = sSQL + "WHERE EM_Department like '" + ddDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
}
```

Please suggest me in proper direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if you add a question mark, this isn't a question!

Comment: Nothing. It just requires a little use of mind.

Comment: @user3041224 do not change your question too much, if your problem **was** how to find selected items do not update question to "how do I use them to query DB?". In case you have problems with that please post **another question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**  you need to iterate through each item of the `ListBox` Control

**Step 2:**  for each `ListBox` `item` check wether it is selected or not using 
`Selected` property

**Step3:** if the item is selected then send a mail to that no.

Try This:

```
           String Selectednos= "";
           foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)                    
                {
                    //no is selected send smsto this no
                    Selectednos+=li.value+";";
                }
            }
```

now using the String `(Selectednos)` you can send sms to all selected no.
Note : mobile numbers are separated using `semicolon ;` here to send `sms` to multiple numbers at a time.
if the delimiter which you use for sending `sms` to mutiple users is different you can change accordingly.

**Solution 2:**

```
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(EM_MobileNo) FROM psbaramati.employee_master ";
String SelectedList="";
int count=0;
foreach(ListItem li in ListBox2.Items )   
{   
if(li.Selected)
{
if(count>0)
SelectedList +=",'" + li.Value.ToString() + "'";
else
SelectedList +="'" + li.Value.ToString() + "'";
count++;
}
}

sSQL = sSQL + "WHERE EM_Department in (" + SelectedList+ ");
```

now try with Query => `sSQL`

Comment: If i want to send sms to all numbers at a time,what is code for to select all records from listbox

Comment: foreach(ListItem li in ListBox2 .Items )
             {
                sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(EM_MobileNo) FROM psbaramati.employee_master ";
                sSQL = sSQL + "WHERE EM_Department like '" + ddDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
            }    it's the my code please suggest me

Comment: @user3041224: check my edited answer with section `solution2`

Comment: thank you sudhakar very much

Comment: @user3041224: are you able to run it now?

Comment: but unable to understand meaning of SelectedList(Is it for mobileNo or many more)

Comment: @user3041224: `SelectedList` is declared as a `string` here which will contain list of `selected mobile numbers` from the `ListBox.`

Comment: But sir its overriding the previous value of the mobile number

Comment: @user3041224: yes sorry, you need to add `+=` while adding string. check my edited answer.

Comment: Another problem is that ,if(li.Selected) condition is showing false thata why it does'nt enters into the count...any reason?

Comment: @user3041224: in your design file you should have `SelctionMode=Multiple` for `ListBox2` check that , please share the code both design and codebehind so that it helps me to understand.

Comment: sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(EM_MobileNo) FROM psbaramati.employee_master ";
 foreach (ListItem li in ListBox2.Items)
             { if (li.Selected)
                 {
                     selectedvalue +=", '"+li.Value+"'";
                 }
                 else
                     count++;
                 selectedvalue += "'"+li.Value+"'";
             }                 
                   sSQL = sSQL + " WHERE EM_Department like '" + ddDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                   sSQL = sSQL + " AND EM_SerialNo IN ('" + selectedvalue  + "')";

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check MSDN first:

- Set [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Multiple`.
- Cycle through [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, selected items have [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to `true`.

Something like this:

```
  <asp:ListBox id="listBox" Rows="3" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True">555 111</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>555 222</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>555 333</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:ListBox>
```

Use:

```
foreach (var listItem in listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected))
{
    string displayText = listItem.Text;
    string value = listItem.Value;

    // Do something with that...
}
```

If you just need a list of numbers to pass to another function like this:

```
void SendSmsTo(IEnumerable<string> numbers, string text)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can use this:

```
var numbers = listBox.Items
    .Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Selected)
    .Select(x => x.Value);

SendSms(numbers, "This is my SMS");
```

Do not forget to add `using System.Linq;`!